# Why is this instance variable nil when accessed in a different unit test?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testunit

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'test/unit'

class Thing
  attr_accessor :foo

  def set_stuff
    @foo = 'bar'
  end
end

class ThingTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def setup
    @thing = Thing.new
  end

  def test_set_stuff
    @thing.set_stuff
    assert 'bar' == @thing.foo
  end

  def test_foo_in_other_test
    puts @thing.foo
    assert 'bar' == @thing.foo
  end
end


# Loaded suite testing
# Started
# nil
# F.
# Finished in 0.00439 seconds.
#
#   1) Failure:
# test_foo_in_other_test(ThingTest) [testing.rb:26]:
# <false> is not true.
#
# 2 tests, 2 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference looks to be that you're not calling @thing.set_stuff in the second test.

Comment: So the state of my object in `setup` doesn't persist through test methods?

Comment: Correct. Your setup method will be called before each and every test method in the test fixture. So to list all of the calls while running these test cases would be
1. setup
2. test_set_stuff
3. teardown
4. setup
5. test_foo_in_other_test
6. teardown

Both setup and teardown are optional. You don't need to have those and in your case you've only defined setup, which is totally fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not as familiar with Test::Unit as RSpec, but I believe the setup() method will be called each time a test is run.  So one @thing will be overwritten by another.

In addition, I've found that you can't assume a particular order for the execution of test cases; often (perhaps all the time?) the tests are run from last to first, as seems to be the case in this instance.